# Neural network can't handle load given

Tags: javascript, php

I found some source code online for a neural network done in PHP. You can find it here: http://pastebin.com/MaqFXkWW

I thought this would be perfect for deciding if something you've drawn in canvas has been drawn before. So I set out to build a proof of concept and build this `neural_trainer.php` script:

```
<? 
require_once ("class_neuralnetwork.php");

$pattern = $_POST['data'];

$n = new NeuralNetwork(90000, 90000, 1);
$n->setVerbose(false);

$n->addTestData($pattern, array (0));

$max = 9;


while (!($success = $n->train(1000, 0.01)) && $max -- > 0) {
    echo "Nothing found...<hr />";
}


if ($success) {
    $epochs = $n->getEpoch();
    echo "Success in $epochs training rounds!<hr />";
}


for ($i = 0; $i < count($n->trainInputs); $i ++) {
    $output = $n->calculate($n->trainInputs[$i]);
    print "<br />Testset $i; ";
    print "expected output = (".implode(", ", $n->trainOutput[$i]).") ";
    print "output from neural network = (".implode(", ", $output).")\n";
}
```

And this is the javascript, which posts to `neural_trainer.php`

```
//canvas1 is 300x300
var img1Data = ctx1.getImageData(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);

$.ajax({
    url: 'neural_training.php',
    data: { data: img },
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

But it keeps throwing `Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted (tried to allocate x bytes)` eventhough I put this at the top of `class_neuralnetwork.php` `ini_set("memory_limit","340M");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);`

Comment: Which statement tries to allocate the memory? By default PHP's max memory limit is configured quite low (8 MB or somethingsuch). You can set it in `php.ini` or (if the server is configured to allow that with the [`ini_set` function](http://php.net/ini_set))

Comment: Oh, I forgot. I set it at the top of class_neuralnetwork.php `ini_set("memory_limit","340M");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

The memory available to PHP is too small. Either increase the memory available to PHP by means of the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) configuration directive or rewrite the script such that it consumes less memory.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that, but just for clarification: is `ini_set("memory_limit","1000M");` a lot for a web application? So can I just leave it like that or do you recommend rewriting it?

Comment: 1 Gigabyte of RAM costs less than 15 minutes of developer time. So if the higher memory limit solves your problem, that would be the way to go.

Comment: No no, a 1G of RAM for a web process is far too large, @user3821544. This is the RAM that will be taken up by one user when they connect, and they'll hang onto it for your long (1000 sec?) runtimes. Ouch! Thus, if you have an 8G server, you would be able to handle only seven concurrent users (leaving space for the operating system, of course). However with a sensible process size, such a server could handle hundreds of concurrent users.

Comment: So now I get a 500 (Internal Server Error)...

Comment: As for a solution, I wonder if you need a queue system? Something like Gearman, perhaps. You can configure a few workers, each with 1G if they really need it, and they pick up and process the work on behalf of the web server. You can then bring your web process down to something like 64M.

Comment: That might be the solution or is there a way to make the size of the 300*300 pixel data smaller. Currently it's an array of 90.000 1's and 0's.